# Trying to insert array into database... (implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed )

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select input where you can choose multiple options. Unfortunately, I have no clue how to insert the values selected into my database. Here is the code I am trying to use, which is giving me an invalid argument passed on my attempt to implode it.

Thanks for any help...

Here is my php:

```
  $distribs = implode("|", $_POST["distributors"]); 
$distribs  = mysql_real_escape_string($distribs ); 


$distribs = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['distributors']);
$sql="UPDATE customers SET distributors = '$distribs'
                                            WHERE id='$id'";
```

Here is my select:

```
  echo "<select name='distributors' multiple='multiple'>";
```

Comment: `$_POST["distributors"]` isn't an array.

Comment: what you getting in `$_POST["distributors"]` ??

Comment: what datatype you are using for distributors  in DB as implode return strings ??

Comment: @alex please enlighten me. my select name is supplosed to be distributors[] rather than just distributors, correct?

Comment: are you getting the selected value in print_r($_POST['distributors'])

Comment: @NullPointer nothing is getting submitted to distributors. not sure if this is what you were asking.

Comment: @DeDav only one value prints/is sent to the database (despite me selecting two or three values...)

Comment: @Alex try this also name='distributors[]'

Comment: you might want to post relevant html also ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
echo "<select name='distributors[]' multiple='multiple'>";
```

Comment: Okay, this is what I had at one point, but for whatever reason, it wasn't working earlier. Now it works! Go figure...I must have had my code wrong elsewhere at the time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST["distributors"];` is not an array, `implode();`  require an array to function,

[PHP.net Function for implode();](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

If your `$_POST` is a correct array format; then implode will convert the array into a single string.

If your $_POST contains information from a `<select> </select>` Then the submission would be a single string which can be inserted into a database without the need for your `implode();` function.

if you are certain that your $_POST is being submitted in an array format. Use as
*DeDav*
Has suggested.

Run this command when your $_POST is populated.

> print_r($_POST['distributors'])

If your using a multiple select. Use as again *DeDav* suggested:

`echo "<select name='distributors[]' multiple='multiple'>";`

Comment: i suspect [explode](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) doesnot [require an  array](http://codepad.org/WjITaLz8). here **explode — Split a string by string** no mention of array

Comment: Simple mistake; shouldn't have mentioned `explode();` This has now been removed from my post.